# Delete duplicate rows with same text

Tags: mysql, sql, text, duplicates

I have table `news` with this fields:

`idNews`
`idArea`
`title`
`text`
`date`

What I want to do is delete all duplicate rows with same `title` and `text` except one (the one with the earliest date) i already try some query without success.

I tried these queries, but they didn't work:

```
DELETE FROM news WHERE idNews NOT IN (SELECT MIN(date) FROM news GROUP BY title,text, date); 

DELETE idNews FROM news WHERE date< date AND title= title and text=text;
```

Comment: Which flavor of sql you are using

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Comment: i already try edit database and use unique but i get an error

ERROR 1071: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: DELETE FROM news WHERE idNews NOT IN ( SELECT MIN(date) FROM news GROUP BY title,text, date) ;


DELETE idNews FROM news WHERE date< date AND title= title and text=text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `idNews` is a key then this should work:

```
delete from news 
where idnews not in (
  select idnews from (
    select idnews from news
    join (
      select title, text, min(date) as min_date 
      from news
      group by title, text
    ) x 
     on news.title = x.title
    and news.text  = x.text 
    and news.date  = x.min_date
  ) a
);
```

The reason for the nested joins is that MySQL won't let you delete data from a table that you're directly referencing in a join. The second level subquery creates a temporary result set that will allow the delete.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f8a3c/1)

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'x.date' in 'on clause'

Comment: @Daggra That's odd, it worked fine when I tried it. I've made a small change, please try now.

Comment: i just change news.date  > x.min_date to get the result that i want but that works :)

ty for the help!!

Answer (score -1):

One of the methods is

```
delete from table as t1 inner join
(
select title,text,min(date) as date from table group by title,text
) as t2 on t1.title=t2.title and t1.text=t2.text 
where t1.date>t2.date;
```

Comment: he is expecting an identifier from table

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from news where title in (
    select title from news group by title having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: It will not delete duplicate records. Go through the questions properly.

Comment: he can check first if any duplications